# How to add Wrapper Div/container element around Wordpress Widget Content

Tags: plugins, widgets

I want to apply style to widget content of Wordpress but I see widget Content area is not having uniform class. TextWidget are having class "textwidget" and that is uniform but other widgets are having "ul" as element for example and class is also different there.

Can I add any wrapper Or a particular Class around content part of every widget in Wordpress?

I got this:

```
function my_widget_content_wrap($content) {
    $content = '<div class="widget-content">'.$content.'</div>';
    return $content;
}
add_filter('widget_text', 'my_widget_content_wrap');
```

but it only works for textwidget which I do not need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`register_sidebar`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar) function has `'before_widget'` and `'after_widget'` arguments that, by default, add `<li>` tags with a class of `widget` around each widget. You can change that in your theme to add an additional `<div>` around each widget if `li.widget` is not a good enough [CSS Selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html) or if your theme removes it.

I don't know what options are in the `register_sidebar()` function for your theme. You would have to change this code to fit your theme.

```
register_sidebar( array(
    'name'          => __( 'Sidebar name', 'theme_text_domain' ),
    'id'            => 'unique-sidebar-id',
    'description'   => __( 'Sidebar name description', 'theme_text_domain' ),
    'class'         => '',
    'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s"><div class="widget-content">',
    'after_widget'  => '</div></li>',
    'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
    'after_title'   => '</h2>'
) );
```

---

Edit:

To isolate just the content, you could style everything in the widget and then style the title. For example, in the style sheet, do something like this:

```
.widget .widgettitle {
    /** Style the widget title. */
}

.widget {
    /** Style the whole widget. */
}
```

The `.widget .wigettitle` selector has greater [specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) and will override the matching styles in `.widget`. The net effect is that only the widget content will be affected by the styles that are overridden.

Comment: This solution will add wrapper outside(before) widgettitle. I want wrapper after widgettitle just for content area in every kinds of widget.

Comment: Have you tried adding the `<div class="widget-content">` to the `after_title` argument? For example: `'after_title' => '</h2><div class="widget-content">'`. I didn't test it.

Comment: I read about this at other places but it gives broken HTML when you do not add title. and sometimes I need to use HTML widget with title.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is to jQuery's [last-child selector](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/).

Comment: I added a CSS way to affect only the widget content. See the edit.

Comment: Cool. I asked here if there is any WP filter/hook etc which I could not search. I see there is none. You tried your best. Thanks.